# Unable to Merge Fleets in Galactic Civilizations III

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

In Galactic Civilizations III I have two fleets with different fleet numbers. Unlike ships that just emerged from the same or nearby star bases I am unable to simply move them in to the same spot and merge them, they merely stack on the tile.

**How do I merge different fleets in Galactic Civilization III?**

Comment: Are these fleets over the logistics cap?

Comment: @Dallium They won't exceed the logistics cap which is shown when hovering any fleet. I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's about **logistics**.

1. Technology
2. Engineering
3. Orbital Manufacturing
4. Orbital Specialization
5. Interstellar Logistics (+10)
6. Logistical Optimization
7. Fleet Logistics (+10)

There are more technologies that increase logistics. It's critical to be able to merge and logistically control many ships simultaneously. You can view the logistics score of a fleet by hovering the mouse over it, currently the bottom statistic. Each ship requires a certain score level of logistics, the larger the ship the more points of logistics it takes to have it work with other ships.

http://galciv.wikia.com/wiki/Logistics